# Should I use Delayed Job for long running background tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I have an application where I want to automatically deactivate a user 72 hours after they have been activated. I have set this up with Delayed Job, but am now wondering if that is the best option.

My question is, if I set a task for 72 hours in the future, will a worker be active for that entire 72 hours? (I'm concerned about this as Heroku charges by the hour)

I'm open to suggestion here as far as better ways of doing this goes. One idea I had was to set this up using an `exp_date` column and check against that at sign in there by eliminating the need for DJ completely.

Comment: What authentication gem are you using?

Comment: You could definitely use a custom devise strategy that you implement after database authenticable that checks the date of creation of the account and then blocks login - much simpler and no need for cron jobs, it just takes effect when the user attempts a login.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the best approach. At least I got to play around with DJ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if I set a task for 72 hours in the future, will a worker be active for that entire 72 hours? (I'm concerned about this as Heroku charges by the hour)

Yes, it will be up all time. Delayed job continuously pings the database to see if there any job in its queue.

And, regarding the best option i think i rather put one column knows as `valid_upto` and put the date till will be active. I only signins (or whatever) to only  those user which has `created_at` dates  less then or equal to `valid_upto` date. And, periodically may be once in month i will run one cron job to remove `invalid` users.

And, like @leesungchul suggested, you can use that, that looks cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workless gem which is an addon for delayed jobs so you don't leave your worker running constantly on heroku.

https://github.com/lostboy/workless

Comment: I've looked at a couple of those, but I'm still unclear as to if a worker would be active for the entire duration of a delay. Locally it appears to be. If that's the case, then even if the worker gets spun down after the job, it would still have been active for a long period even if it was just waiting and would incur the costs of having an active worker for that period.